# Undefined method <model_name>_index_path for rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Okay, this continues to baffle me:

1) This is in my controller (personalias_controller.rb)

```
def new
  @personalia = Personalia.new
end
```

2) I've got a model called personalia.rb

3) I've got

```
resources :personalias
```

in routes.rb

Still I get undefined method `personalia_index_path' when I try to render the personalia form as such (from within views/personalias/new.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @personalia do |f| %>
```

It's driving me nuts :-|

Comment: You counterchecked with `rake routes`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably becouse personalias is not the plural of personalia, you can check this in your console using `"personalia".pluralize` you could add an inflection and restart your app, here is how:

config > initializers > inflections.rb

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'personalia', 'personalias'
end
```