# Rails getting the error: First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, nested, null

I've been getting this error for a couple days and I'm totally blocked. I tried redoing the model (I'm following the rails starting guide) and just not getting anywhere.

> First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

I have time_delta as a nested class of stock im trying to create a form to view and create new time_deltas on a stock's show and I keep getting the above error.

Heres my time_delta controller:

```
 class TimeDeltasController < ApplicationController
    def new
    @stock = Stock.find(params[:stock_id])
    @time_delta = @stock.time_deltas.build
    respond_with(@time_delta)
  end
  def create
    @stock = Stock.find(params[:stock_id])
    @time_delta = @stock.time_deltas.build(params[:stock])
    @time_delta.save
  end

end
```

Heres my view for the specific stock

```
<h1> Stock </h1>
<table> 
    <tr>
        <th>Stock</th>
        <th>Hashtag</th>        
    </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><%= @stock.name %></td>
            <td><%= @stock.hashtag %></td>
        </tr>
</table>

<h2>Deltas: </h2>
  <table> 
    <tr>
      <th>Stock</th>
      <th>Hashtag</th>    
    </tr>
  <% @stock.deltas.each do |delta| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= @delta.start %></td>
      <td><%= @delta.length %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>

<h2>Add a TimeDelta:</h2>
<%= form_for([@stock,@time_delta]) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :start %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :start %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :length %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :length %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', stocks_path%>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_stock_path(@stock)%>
```

Heres how I added the route in my routes.rb:

```
  resources :stocks do
    resources :time_deltas
  end
```

Any information would be greatly appreciated, I'm really stuck.

EDIT: Stocks controller stuff

```
def show
        @time_delta = @stock.time_deltas.build

        @stock = find_stock
    end
private
def find_stock

  return Stock.find(params[:id])


end
```

Comment: You also need to define `@stock` and `@time_delta` in your `new` action.

Comment: @Vee fixed, still getting the same error though

Comment: Is `Stock.find(params[:stock_id])` in the `new` action succeeding?  How is your route setup?

Comment: Assuming the view code is for show action of your Stock controller, you should create @time_delta there.

Comment: @vee when you say the route which specific route do you mean? Donatats Stundys - that is the code for my time_delta controller

Comment: I meant 'Heres my view for the specific stock' part. Your 'new' action from TimeDeltasController is never called here. You need to define @time_delta in show action of StockController like you did in TimeDeltasController.

Comment: @DonatasStundys so I added '@time_delta = @stock.time_deltas.build'to my show for my stock controller and now it's giving me this error on that line 'undefined method `time_deltas' for nil:NilClass'

Comment: Can you show me your StocksController show action? Do you define @stock there?

Comment: @DonatasStundys added to OP

Comment: '@stock = find_stock' should go before '@time_delta'. Now @stock is undefined.

Comment: So fixed that and now I'm back at this error 'undefined method `stock_time_delta_index_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fff1c287440>:0x007fff1c286310>' on this line of the view '  <%= form_for([@stock,@time_delta]) do |f| %>' This is the error that stumped me to begin with.

Comment: Heading in the right direction. Can you show the part of Stock model where you define the association with TimeDelta model.

Comment: Yep here it is: 'has_many :time_deltas' and in time_delta model: ' belongs_to :stock' @DonatasStundys

Comment: The problem here is that ruby thinks 'delta' is plural of 'deltum', which breaks it's conventions. Follow the answer in this thread to solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478612/undefined-method-model-name-index-path-for-rails-3-2

Comment: @DonatasStundys that fixed that !! Thank you !! How can I approve your answer  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access @time_delta variable in your stocks/show view, but it is not set. Add the following line to StocksController#show action.

```
@time_delta = @stock.time_deltas.build
```

EDIT:

Also there is a problem with the naming of your TimeDelta model, because in Ruby 'delta' is plural of 'deltum'. To adhere to Rails conventions, change the the model name to TimeDeltum or alternatively tell Rails to use 'deltas' as the plural form of 'delta'. You can learn how to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478612/undefined-method-model-name-index-path-for-rails-3-2).

Comment: So the pluralization fixed the time delta, however adding the line mentioned before the edit gives me this error 'Could not find table 'time_deltas'' any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The error basically means you've not set the variables for use in [`form_for`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for)

As you're a beginner, let me explain how it works:

> `form_for` is basically an instance method (helper) which takes ActiveRecord objects, and outputs them into an HTML form. Your definitions of elements (`f.____field`) are for the method to determine which HTML to output
>
> Like all methods, `form_for` has [arguments/parameters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_%28computer_programming%29) which it relies on to help the method run correctly. The parameters for `form_for` include a correctly formatted ActiveRecord object, which is why you have to call `Model.new` each time you want to use it

Your error means the method cannot process the variables (objects) you've sent, either from lack of data (`empty`) or non-existence (`nil`). To fix this, as `@vee` has mentioned, you need to make sure your `form_for` is receiving the correct data

---

I would try this:

```
class TimeDeltasController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @stock = Stock.find(params[:stock_id])
    @time_delta = @stock.time_deltas.build
    respond_with(@stock, @time_delta)
  end
  def create
    @stock = Stock.find(params[:stock_id])
    @time_delta = @stock.time_deltas.build(params[:stock])
    @time_delta.save
  end

end
```

You should read up on [respond_with](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_with) to see how it works

Comment: I'm still getting this paths error now 'undefined method `stock_time_delta_index_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fc212401b00>:0x007fc2178cb500>' on the line '   <%= form_for([@stock,@time_delta]) do |f| %>'